# Instagram logout programmatically

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, instagram, instagram-api

Adobe AIR, apache flex sdk, application for instagram using Instagram API.
When i need to logout user i use this simply code:

```
protected function logOut():void
{               
    var urlRequest: URLRequest = new URLRequest();
    var urlLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
    urlRequest.url = "https://instagram.com/accounts/logout/";
    urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, logOutCompleted)
    urlLoader.load(urlRequest);
}
```

but it doesnt logouting, it stays logged with previous user. Any suggestions why request doesnt work?

Comment: it changed few days ago, the url does not logout anymore :(

Comment: is it possible to logout from app somehow?

Comment: dont know a way to do, i'm trying to find out from Instagram

Answer (score 0):

Found solution.

```
var urlLoader: URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlRequest.url = "https://www.instagram.com/accounts/logout/";
urlRequest.requestHeaders = [new URLRequestHeader("Cookie", "sessionid=''")]
```